# Does DragGestureRecognizer consume mouse events, and can I prevent that?

Tags: java, mouse

In a fairly complicated codebase, there is functionality both to 
(a) drag objects places, implemented with DragGestureRecognizer, 
(b) and the ability to drag boxes around things to select them, implemented via e.g. mousePressed() listeners.

Normally they behave "correctly".

However there are *some* objects which are marked immovable, and when the user begins a mouse gesture on top of one of them, the DragGestureRecognizer is finding it, and apparently consuming the mouse event.

What I'd like to be able to do is e.g. add something to my DragGestureRecognizer to say "oh look, we found an immovable object, let's not have this be a drag after all", and allow the dragging-a-box-around-things to take control.

I realize I'm not providing code because there is way too much to provide, but short of disabling the DragGestureRecognizer entirely (bad), I haven't found a way to get it to (selectively) turn loose of mouse events. Any help much appreciated!